# uploading 3D object in mapbox

Tags: 3d, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am using map box and want to simulate a 3D scene on a map.
Is it possible to upload a ***3D object/image*** in Map Box and Geo-reference it? if yes, how? which formats are supported?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible now to upload a 3D object, but you can integrate a 3D model client side in Mapbox GL JS, using a CustomLayer and three.js. This example shows how that is done: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/